# Remove duplicate select options

Tags: angular

Using Angular 5, I created a select dropdown that is being populated by data from a web request. I'd like to remove items that have duplicate object properties of `DocumentGroup`. How would I do this without combining jQuery and Angular?

Here is my HTML:

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option *ngFor="let doc of docs; [value]="doc.DocumentGroup">
    <span>
      {{doc.DocumentGroup}}
    </span>
  </option>
</select>
```

The TS for the web request:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get("https://test.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Document Separator Barcodes')/items?$orderBy=ID").subscribe(data => {
      console.log("data", data);
      console.log("data.value", data['value']);
      this.docs = data['value'];
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by looping through the results, adding each `DocumentGroup` property to an array, and then getting the unique items from that array by using the method that @72GM mentioned.

The entire function now looks like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get("https://portal.oldnational.com/corporate/portalsupport/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Document Separator Barcodes')/items?$orderBy=ID").subscribe(data => {
      console.log("data", data);
      console.log("data.value", data['value']);
      this.docs = data['value'];

      for (let i = 0; i < this.docs.length; i++) {
          this.docs[i];
          console.log("DocGroup loop", this.docs[i].DocumentGroup)
          this.docgroups.push(this.docs[i].DocumentGroup)
          console.log("DocGroupArray", this.docgroups)
      }

      this.unique = Array.from(new Set(this.docgroups));
      console.log(this.unique)

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you would do this in your typescript file and filter out any duplicates before populating your this.docs collection... similar to this

https://www.codementor.io/tips/8243973127/how-to-remove-duplicates-within-a-javascript-array-using-es6-in-just-one-line