# How can I remove duplicate data in dropdown option?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<option *ngFor="let type of UserTypes; let i = index" [ngValue]="type.id">
    <span>{{type.name}}</span>
</option>
```

I want to remove the duplicate data in dropdown option

[image]

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48890226/remove-duplicate-select-options

Comment: hm, sorry but I don't use https or web request

Comment: @vince it doesn't matter what the source of the data is. The basic premise is you'll have an array of objects and you'll create a unique array from this.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to filter the original list (i.e. `UserTypes`) before iterating it with `*ngFor`, so the first step is to identify how to remove duplicates from this array.

You will need to decide what is considered a duplicate, i.e. which key in the object will be checked for uniqueness. For the purposes of this example I will consider that you have a property `name` in your object which needs to be unique. The downstream logic will therefore delete any object which contains a `name` value that has already been encountered earlier in the list. There are plenty of examples of how to do this in [other SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects).

Function copied from answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56768137/9987590

`utils.ts`

```
function getUniqueListBy(arr, key) {
    return [...new Map(arr.map(item => [item[key], item])).values()]
}
```

You could either:

---

- Filter the data in the `.ts` file, storing it in a new variable (e.g. `filteredUserTypes`) and then use that as the subject of your `*ngFor`

`component.ts`

```
ngOnInit() {
  // Place this inside your .subscribe() block instead of ngOnInit() if you are fetching data asynchronously/from an API
  this.filteredUserTypes = getUniqueListBy(this.UserTypes, 'name') 
}
```

`component.html`

```
<option *ngFor="let type of filteredUserTypes" [ngValue]="type.id">
    <span>{{type.name}}</span>
</option>
```

---

- Create a custom pipe which does the filtering (e.g. `FilterPipe`)

`pipe.ts`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe<T extends {}> implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: T[], key: keyof T): T[] {
    return items.length ? getUniqueListBy(items, key) : []
  }
}
```

`component.html`

```
<option *ngFor="let type of UserTypes | filter : 'name'" [ngValue]="type.id">
    <span>{{type.name}}</span>
</option>
```